# 'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'replace' в Django 2.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть модель:

```py
class GoodsCategory(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'категория товаров'
        verbose_name_plural = 'категории товаров'

    caption = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='название',  unique=True, max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='описание', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption

class Good(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'товар'
        verbose_name_plural = 'товары'

    caption = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='название', unique=True, max_length=255)
    brief_description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='краткое описание', blank=True)
    full_description = models.TextField(
        verbose_name='полное описание', blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='изображение', blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        GoodsCategory, models.CASCADE, verbose_name='категория')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption
```

есть представление:

```py
def catalog(request):
    data = dict()
    for cat in GoodsCategory.objects.all():
        goods = Good.objects.filter(category=cat)[:3]
        data[cat] = goods
    return render(request, 'mainapp/catalog.html', {'data': data, })
```

и есть шаблон:

```html
{% load static %}
<h1>Каталог товаров</h1>
{% for cat, goods in data.items %}
    <h3><a href="{% url 'catalog:category' cat.id %}">Категория "{{ cat.caption }}"</a></h3>
        {% for g in goods %}
            <img src="{% static g.image %}" alt="">
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

никак не погу понять, почему при вызове данного шаблона получаю ошибку

```
Internal Server Error: /catalog/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "Y:\Programming\Python\django_basic\myshop\mainapp\views.py", line 14, in catalog
    return render(request, 'mainapp/catalog.html', {'data': data, })
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62,
in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py",
line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 937, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 209, in render
    nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\templatetags\static.py", line
106, in render
    url = self.url(context)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\templatetags\static.py", line
103, in url
    return self.handle_simple(path)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\templatetags\static.py", line
118, in handle_simple
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 331, in url
    url = filepath_to_uri(name)
  File "D:\Envs\myshop\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 249,
in filepath_to_uri
    return quote(path.replace("\\", "/"), safe="/~!*()'")
AttributeError: 'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Что не так с вызовом статики?

Comment: Есть конечно вариант с доп.методом, возвращающем путь к файлу, типа такого:
```python
class Good(models.Model):

 ...

    def get_image_path(self):
        return str(self.image)
```
но хотелось бы знать идеоматический вариант

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{% static g.image.url %}" alt="">
```

вы должны передать строку в шаблон `{% static "string" %}`
а `g.image` - это объект, надо `g.image.url` передать